# Horizontally Justify List Items

Tags: php, html, css, html-lists

I am trying to distribute three `<li>` elements across a `<ul>` that is 92% width. So far I am just centering the `<ul>` with this class:

```
.centeralign {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

but after trying numerous methods of distributing these `<li>` elements evenly across the `<ul>`, I still cant seem to make them distribute. I get three `<li>`'s looking like the image below.

Here is the HTML/PHP code:

```
<ul class="featuredevs centeralign">
<?php
    $developers = array();

    $sql = "SELECT `userid` FROM UserData WHERE `name`!='' AND `profileImg`!='' ORDER BY `userid` desc limit 3;";
    include 'SQLaccount.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($accountCon,$sql) or die ("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $sql);
    $numOfDevs = $result->num_rows;
    mysqli_close($accountCon);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($developers, $row['userid']);
    }


    <?php
$cnt = 3;
foreach ($developers as $userid) {
    $name = "";
    $profileImg = "";

    $sql = "SELECT `name`, `profileImg` FROM UserData WHERE `userid`=$userid;";
    include 'SQLaccount.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($accountCon,$sql) or die ("Error: ". mysql_error(). "    with query ". $sql);
    mysqli_close($accountCon);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $name = $row['name'];
        $profileImg = $row['profileImg'];
        break;
    }

    echo('<li class="developerdiv">');

    echo ("<a class='' href='profile.php?user=$userid'>");

    echo("<img class='featureimage img-rounded' src='userPictures/$profileImg' alt='$name Profile Picture>");

    echo("div class='devinfo'>");
    echo("<p class='devname'>" . $name . "</p>");
    echo("<p class='devdesc'>" . $userid . "</p>");
    echo("</div>");

    echo ('</a>');

    echo('</li>');


    $cnt += 1;

}


    ?>
    </ul>
```

Any Suggestions Much Appreciated!

Comment: You have a missing closing `'` here in `alt` attribute `echo("<img class='featureimage img-rounded' src='userPictures/$profileImg' alt='$name Profile Picture>");` Additionally i suggest you write your strings inside `'` in php code so you can write html attrs with `"`

Comment: So I put together this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Pz3nd/ - and I only see 1 li element. Do you want the name and userid to be in separate lis?

Comment: No the reason you only see 1 li is because it automatically displays 3  of the li's through the php code.